# How is the lParam of LVITEM stored in virtual list control?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

In a virtual list control, I can obtain a `LVITEM` by a function `OnGetdispinfoList`. But if I add additional information here through `lParam` and assign this to `LVITEM`, Is this pointer-to-data (my guess so far) really stored in the `LVITEM`? Because virtual list control doesn't maintain the data but only display what is needed. So how is the lifecycle of the information in lParam?
Thank you

Comment: Have you read [How to Use Virtual List-View Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/use-virtual-list-view-controls) yet?

Comment: Virtual listviews do not record any per-item data. You have to be able to identify the item purely from its index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtual list-view controls indeed do not maintain any data, hence you don't call `ListView_InsertItem()` (or `LVM_INSERTITEM`) but you call `ListView_SetItemCountEx()` (or `LVM_SETITEMCOUNT`) instead .

The `LVN_GETDISPINFO` notification is a call-back function (well, message). You have to provide the information you are being asked. Your code should examine the `mask` member of the `LVITEM` srtucture and fill-in the data requested. It doesn't matter where this structure is stored and its lifetime, you don't have any control over it anyway. It's probably stored in the stack or some temporary array into the memory, but you should make no assumptions. And of course do not store things like a handle or pointer in the `lParam` member of the `LVITEM` srtucture for a virtual list-view control and expect them to be stored. I would actually be very surprised to find that the `LVIF_PARAM` bit of the `mask` is set for virtual list-view control (ie the system is asking you to fill-in the `lParam` member), it makes no sense to me; you can add some code to test it, but I don't think it will ever be set.